# Progress bar with negative value .css(width, )

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I search and research into the foruns, of all the internet... but I don't found it the solution...

I need, this:

```
<label> Name:
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />
</label> 
<div class="container">
        <div class="progress progress-danger progress-striped active">
            <div class="bar" id="progBar" ></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

So, I want that when the user exits the field (onBlur), he receives the amount of characters and return as the value of the progress bar, and if this parameter is negative, return as the value of the progress bar, only negative, or is the bar again.

The code of bar and JS...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("*").blur(function() {
    var $bar = $("#progBar");
    var $name = $("name");

    if ($("#name").val().length > 2) {
        $bar.css('width', "30%");
    } else {
        $bar.css('width', "-30%"); //How, I do this????????
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by negative width? In css, negative width are not allowed.

Read it here or google it.

http://www.css3.com/css-width/

> ## CSS WIDTH
>
> This property specifies the width of an element’s rendering box for
>   block-level and replaced elements. Negative values are not allowed.

Positive width is a property, if you are looking for the width on the left side of element, its not negative width, its still width, you may have a different element to shohw that width.

Here is what you are looking for.

## **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ybPzP/18/)**

This would work for 2 input fields,

```
if (($("#name").val().length > 2) && ($("#email").val().length>2)) {
    $('#positive').css('width','100%');
} else if($("#name").val().length > 2 || $("#email").val().length>2){
    $('#positive').css('width','50%');
} else{
    $('#positive').css('width','0%');
}
```

You may also like to see jquery ui's [progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#default),

A jsFiddle showing that is here.

## **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybPzP/24/)**

Comment: Actually this is the answer, you cannot have negative values, you can do something like this though, http://jsfiddle.net/ybPzP/14/

Comment: And use gradient if you want it 30% filled.

Comment: But, I wanted, this... [Register Galk HTML5](http://register.galk.me/) What do you think? @Optimus Prime

Comment: Oh you don't need to use negative width for that at all, you just need to decrease width. Should I explain more?

Comment: added a jsfiddle to the answer, please see the demo. I hope it helps, if it solved the problem, please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: So, if don't much uncomfortable, explain to me how to do it better, with bootstrap i'm stressing the visual... And I have a big formulary, to do

Comment: Okay let me see. I hope there is no problem understanding this piece of code?

Comment: @BrunoCasali Do you know about jquery's progressbar? http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#default Use that to give it a better look.

Comment: I have added a demo showing jquery's progressbar too. And hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Ok, @Optimus Prime, I did try the jQuery iu, and I post the result when I finish!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set, both, the left margin and the width of the progressbar in order to use it with negative values.

Take a look at this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("*").blur(function() {
    var $bar = $("#progBar");
    var $name = $("#name");

    if ($("#name").val().length > 2) {
        $bar.css('width', "30%").css("margin-left","50%");
    } else {
        var x=-30;
        $bar.css('width', Math.abs(x) + "%").css("margin-left", (50 + x) + "%");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<label>Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required /></label> 
<div class="container">
 <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger active" id="progBar" role="progressbar" style="width:30%;margin-left:20%;"></div> 
 </div>
</div>
```